# Airline Ground Operations via ACARS

Tags: airline-operations, ground-operations, acars

I read about the ACARS "In Range" request pilots can send to request cabin services, lavatory services, wheel chairs, assistance for unaccompanied minors, etc. What about other services such as catering and potable water; those were not shown in the "In Range" request page. Do pilots have to make those request via radio or are those request handled by dispatch?

Any insight into how all this works (who is requesting what service) would be appreciated.

Also, is the catering company providing the potable water as well or are those two separate providers?

Answer (score 1):

That'd depend on the airline, the airport, and the handler.

I'm only somewhat familiar with how it's done where I work, which is probably not the way it's done everywhere.

We have a central computer system that keeps track of all ground movements of aircraft and will alert the handler responsible for the operating airline of a flight as to which gate/parking the aircraft is going to be serviced at. The handler can then go out and provide the services contracted for that flight by that airline.

I guess the aircrew can request additional services by radio or through the gate telephone system through the ground crew as well if needed, but that'd be outside of the reach of the system I work with so I have no details as to how that'd work.